# Yah! we are not missing any dSYMs

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

dsym file is missing for latest build.So I have gone through the instruction on below link https://docs.fabric.io/ios/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html and upload the .zip file manually. on successfully upload message it is showing below image.
[image]

On going back to dashboard the message "unsymbolicated crashes from missing dSYMs.
I am getting this after 30 mins of successful upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks aednichols, I have faced this issue because I am still using old Febric Mac app. Issue fixed after updating fabric app and cocopod to latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Our build process uploads dSYMs automatically and we too saw this message for a release put out yesterday. First time we've ever gotten it.

It could be that Fabric is temporarily behind on symbolication, giving the appearance of missing symbol files.

Comment: Nice to hear you, I am using fabric for build process but first time I am missing it. And this crass report is very important to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested that,missing a dSYM is a rare occurrence when our Mac app wasn't able to get the dSYM over to our system to process crash reports. For data fidelity reasons, we only display crashes that we can symbolicate. Use Spotlight on the UUID to locate the missing dSYM, zip it up and upload it straight from your dashboard! You can also use this command:

mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == ”

in an open terminal to locate the dSYM as well.

Once we process the missing dSYM, you should see crash reports in your dashboard :)

Comment: I have already tried it, as I mention in missing-dsyms.html link